# Change the style of ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

Im working on my actionbar and I'm trying to change the style, I want the background white and the text color blue, Im doing the following to the style.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/action_bar</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/top_bar</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/cyan_500</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" 
                 parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTitleTextBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTitleTextBarStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorRB</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

And nothing is happening, is for API 15 to 22.
I have managed to change the background by code doing this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reasonlocation);
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar mAb = getSupportActionBar();
    mAb.setTitle(getString(R.string.reasonandlocation));
    mCd.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    mAb.setBackgroundDrawable(mCd);
    ...
}
```

If you know how can I solve this, either by style.xml or by code, I will appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it by code, adding the following to my previus code in the onCreate

```
    Spannable text = new SpannableString(mAb.getTitle());
    text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRB)), 0, text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    mAb.setTitle(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:` platform related prefix from `android:actionBarStyle`.